# Excel VBA - dropping and adding zeros in a specified character count

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to build a vba code to build txt files that we use to test with.  I am running into an issue.  Some of my results will have .00 which I made dropped off using `Str = Str & "00" & Left(CashRightJust(Range("h63"), 11), 9)`
This basically is telling it to look at cell H63, right justified the amount but left justify the end by 9 to drop cents if it is "00".
My problem is we now need to test for it to have actual change like .25.  Using this code alone adds a zero at the end of the change.  I need to adjust this code to reflect if it is more then .00 do not edit or add zeros

I hope this makes sense.  I am still fairly new at this and have gotten pretty far but there are still some moments I am lost.  Thank you.

[Spreadsheet created to build code to send to txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBzhP.png)

```
    Function Detail_Rec1()




    Dim strlencount As Integer
    Dim strspacer As Integer



    If Range("b63").Value <> "5" Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    Str = Str & Range("b63").Value        **Result: 5**
    Str = Str & Range("c63").Value        **Result: 400**
    Str = Str & Range("d63").Value        **Result: 1234567**    

    Str = Module1.SpaceAdd(Str, 1)        **Result: 1 space**

    Str = Str & Trim(Range("e63").Value)
    strlencount = Len(Trim(Range("e63").Value))
    strspacer = 30 - strlencount
    Str = Module1.SpaceAdd(Str, strspacer) **Result: Company name with spacefill for 30 character; name is left justified**

   Str = Str & Trim(Range("f63").Value)
    strlencount = Len(Trim(Range("f63").Value))
    strspacer = 11 - strlencount
    Str = Module1.SpaceAdd(Str, strspacer)   **Result: Company ID number; left justify; space filled total 11 characters**

     Str = Str & Range("G63").Value          Result: 116

    Str = Str & CashRightJust(Range("h63"), 11)   **Result: 1000; only 1000 no cents; dollars only; 11 character zero filled right justify**
    Str = Str & CashRightJust(Range("i63"), 11)**Result: 1000; only 1000 no cents; dollars only; 11 character zero filled right justify**
    Str = Str & CashRightJust(Range("j63"), 11)**Result: 1000; only 1000 no cents; dollars only; 11 character zero filled right justify**

    Str = Str & Trim(Range("k63").Value)
    strlencount = Len(Trim(Range("k63").Value))
    strspacer = 4 - strlencount
    Str = Module1.ZeroAdd(Str, strspacer)  **Result: Rate of 4 characters entered; 4 character length**


    Str = Module1.SpaceAdd(Str, 1)   **Result: 1 space**

    Str = Str & CashRightJust(Range("l63"), 11)   **Result: 3348.75 needs to be 334875.  11 characters, right justified, no decimal.**  


    Str = Str & CashRightJust(Range("m63"), 11)


    Str = Str & CashRightJust(Range("n63"), 11)


    Str = Str & CashRightJust(Range("o63"), 11)



    Str = Str & "00000" & Right(Range("p63").Value, 6)
    strlencount = Len(Trim(Range("p63").Value))
    strspacer = 6 - strlencount
    Str = Module1.ZeroAdd(Str, strspacer)
```

[Excel image of line being coded][How text file should appear][2]2]

My end result for what I need is

23.45 - 2345
23.00 - 2300 unless the spec is saying dollars only then it needs to be 23
No rounding.
I hope this helps out more with the visuals

Added Info:  My module that is used for the $ amts currently is following:

```
  If Str = 0 Then
        CashRightJust = ZeroAdd(Str2, c)
        Exit Function
    Else
        If InStr(Str, ".") > 0 Then
            Str2 = Right(Str, 2)

            If InStr(Str2, ".") > 0 Then
                strnew = Str & "0"
            Else
                strnew = Str
            End If
        Else
            strnew = Str & "00"
        End If
```

[Excel snapshot of info being coded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBzhP.png)

54001234567 Bob's Tires                   987654321  116000000010000000000005000000009503525 00000334875

This is how it is coming out:
54001234567 Bob's Tires                   987654321  1160000010000000000005000000000950003525 000334875

I could not post the image of the txt file I don't have enough reputations; sorry; this is how it should appear

Comment: Can you add a few sample input and desired output values? It's not very clear what your function does.

Comment: Why not something like `if Right(Str, 3) <> ".00" then Str = Str & ".00"`?

Comment: I can try:  I will try what you said Matt and let you know if that works.

Comment: What I need to have happen is some of my cells have xx.XX (change), some are zeros.  The specs I need to follow is some need to go to the txt file with only dollars and some can go to the file with the dollars and change amount minus the decimal.

Comment: @MattCremeens - It appears when I use this it is not dropping the decimal to make a straight number with the decimal though?

Comment: @MattCremeens - I ran the file and it dropped all dollars amounts if they were greater, maybe I entered it wrong?

Comment: @LizaHunt I don't think I understand what you are needing. I thought if there were no cents, then add `.00`; otherwise, leave it alone.

Comment: @MattCremeens ; If there are no cents there will be times I need the 00 added without the decimal and there are times where the 00 needs to be dropped bc the specs are asking for dollars only. I apologize if how I am wording it is confusing.

Comment: @LizaHunt No worries. I just have trouble understanding things sometimes. What situation would arise that you need the `00` dropped and what situations would arise where you need the `.00` added?

Comment: Ok I will try to word this correctly;

Comment: In line one of my txt file which is Function Details Rec1 in my VBA -
Str = Str & "00" & Left(CashRightJust(Range("h63"), 11), 9)
    Str = Str & "00" & Left(CashRightJust(Range("i63"), 11), 9)
    Str = Str & "00" & Left(CashRightJust(Range("j63"), 11), 9)
This code is required to have dollars only.  It needs to be 11 characters long, right justified zero filled without the decimal.  If the cell that holds the amount to go contains any cents that is to be dropped without rounding

Comment: Str = Str & "00" & Left(CashRightJust(Range("l63"), 11), 9)

       Str = Str & CashRightJust(Range("m63"), 11)

       Str = Str & CashRightJust(Range("n63"), 11)

       Str = Str & CashRightJust(Range("o63"), 11)
These lines in the same Function need to have the exact amount (dollars and cents) 11 characters, zero filled without the decimal

I am following specs of a publication for tax filing that requires formatting for the input file to be sent online for the tax payer

Comment: @LizaHunt Do you just need the decimal removed? I'm sorry, I'm still having trouble following and I want to help. How do you know if you have a dollar amount? Will there be a dollar sign?

Comment: @MattCremeens : never any decimals or dollar signs.  Only to be numeric for the money amount or rates.  Sorry I tried to format the vba code but it would not let me

Comment: @LizaHunt but your code tests to see if a decimal is in the string.

Comment: @MattCremeens: Correct bc if there dollars and cents that the spec requires they need to appear with 00 at the end of the dollar.  This is where I am totally lost,  I think my module needs to have more If ....Then in there to cover the fact if they need to be dropped and if the cents need to stay;  but after looking at this for 3 weeks I can not figure out where I need to add more

Comment: @LizaHunt Can you give me an example of every pattern of input and what the output would be for each example?

Comment: @MattCremeens; I will edit the question up top to show the code and screenshots of what it should be.  I will also include a screen shot of the txt file it goes to; give me a few I am working on another project at the same time

Comment: @MattCremeens; All info should be there to cover what is happening.  I appreciate your patience with me on this.

Comment: @LizaHunt so the first line is the input and the 2nd line is the expected output? I thought there was more than one scenario?

Comment: @MattCremeens     hmm yes there is.  I am not sure how to show this any other way.  The excel line I sent you is the input.  The second line of the txt file is the expect output.  The first line of the txt file is what is happening which is wrong.  The character and formatting of the amount are not right.

Comment: @LizaHunt it appears as though you just lopped off some leading zeros between the two lines. Is that all you want to do?

Comment: @MattCremeens; I would want them off it it is dollar only and need to be right justified.  If that is not the case there would be more zeros leading up until 11 characters including the dollar/cent amount.

Comment: @MattCremeens; rephrase the txt file answer; I noticed it pasted backwards.  The first line is how it should look and the second like is how it is currently coming out.  I noticed I answered that question backwards

Comment: @LizaHunt and what does it look like originally?

Comment: @LizaHunt so you know it's a dollar amount if it is 11 characters long and contains leading zeros?

Comment: 54001234567 Bob's Tires 987654321 1160000010000000000005000000000950003525 000334875
right after the 116 on line 2 It should be 11 character, dollar only, no decimals right justified.  The amount is suppose to be 1000 but is showing as 100000 (cents are at the end)

Comment: At the end of the line it is suppose to be 950 (no cents/decimal, only dollars, right justified, 11 characters)  As of right now it is showing 95000.

Comment: @MattCremeens; yes all dollar amounts in the specs are 11  characters with leading zeros

Comment: @LizaHunt So we need to examine the last 11 characters of each line, trim all leading zeros from that substring and trim the last two zeros from that substring. Do I understand the problem?

Comment: @MattCremeens    Yes unless the dollar/cent is required then I wouldn't want to trim it

Comment: But how do you know if they are required?

Comment: by the specs I have to follow on a publication for NY

Comment: So you need two different pieces of code, one for when dollars and cents are required and one for when they aren't? What needs to happen if they are required? Just leave it alone?

Comment: if they are required then I can just format the cell for text and it should be left alone.  The only issue I was having with that is it was rounding so I did a Fixed(cell,2,false) on the cell and that seemed to fix that issue so far

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this? It assumes your entire string is in cell `A1` and that this is the situation where dollars and cents are not required (I assume you can handle the situation where they are because it sounds like you more or less leave the string alone in that case).

```
lenOfStr = 11
newStr = ""
subStr = Right(Cells(1, 1), lenOfStr)
If Right(subStr, 2) = "00" Then 'we need to keep these
    lenOfStr = 9
End If
foundLeftmost = False
For i = 1 To lenOfStr
    If Mid(subStr, i, 1) <> "0" and Mid(subStr, i, 1) <> "." Then
        newStr = newStr & Mid(subStr, i, 1) 'start collecting for the new string
        foundLeftmost = True
    End If
    If foundLeftmost and Mid(subStr, i, 1) <> "." Then 'need to include zeros that may show up in the middle of the substring
        newStr = newStr & Mid(subStr, i, 1)
    End If
Next i
subStr = newStr
```

The end result is stored in `subStr`. Hopefully I understood your problem correctly. Let me know if I didn't.

Comment: Let me just clarify before I use this in the code.  If I am reading this right It is calling for a field of 11 characters; right justifying with 11 character.  If the second position is a 00?  What if the 2nd position is .63.  Will it keep those too if needed. I only ask bc it says = .

Comment: The string you provided me as input is much longer than 11 characters. This code gets the rightmost 11 characters. It deletes all leading zeros and keeps the rightmost two zeros, if any. It ignores `.` What should be done about any decimals in the string?

Comment: so taking what you wrote how about just using a Function Dollarconvert as a module to use as a string

Comment: Function DollarConvert(ByVal Str As String, ByVal i As Integer) As String

DollarConvert = Mid(Str, 1, i) & "." & Mid(Str, i + 1, Len(Str) - i)

End Function

Comment: Actually, I changed the code to grab zeros that may show up in the middle of the string. I don't think a function is necessary, but feel free to adapt the code in what way works best for you. I'm still unsure how you want decimals treated.

Comment: No decimals can go over in the code to the txt file.  Only numeric.  If the cents need to be dropped only the dollar amt goes over, if the cents are to be included it goes over as the whole number 12.50 - 1250 with no decimal

Comment: So all decimals in the string always need to be deleted?

Comment: OK. I have edited the above code to address the fact that decimals need to be deleted in the string.

Comment: I will run this code through and see what happens.  Will check back in tomorrow with results.  Thank you for spending your day assisting me I was so lost on this one.

Comment: I'm happy to help. I'll be curious to see how it goes.